# Git pack filenames -- what is the digest?

Tags: git, pack

Git stores individual objects in `.git/objects/ab/cdefgh...` where `ab` is the first byte of the SHA1 digest.

However, pack files don't follow the same naming policy, and I can find no documentation on how it is named. Any insights?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pack files are kept in `objects/pack`, which is documented in [gitrepository layout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html#_description).  Within this directory, they are stored as pairs of an index file and the pack file itself, called, for example:

```
pack-a862cfa8b080773290073999c800a2e655ef9b5d.idx
pack-a862cfa8b080773290073999c800a2e655ef9b5d.pack
```

How the SHA1sum in those filenames is calculated is explained in the [git-pack-objects](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-objects.html#_options) documentation (my emphasis):

> Write into a pair of files (.pack and .idx), using <base-name> to determine the name of the created file. When this option is used, the two files are written in <base-name>-<SHA1>.<pack,idx> files. **<SHA1> is a hash of the sorted object names to make the resulting filename based on the pack content,** and written to the standard output of the command.

The [object names](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_object_name) are the SHA1sums of the objects within the pack file.

Comment: Some filesystems perform poorly with a large number of entries in a single directory. The loose objects “fan out” into `objects/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/` to limit the number of entries each directory has to hold. If the loose objects were stored directly under `objects/`, it could end up with many thousands of entires before being automatically packed. `objects/pack/` does not fan out because it typically needs to store only a very small number of files.

Comment: This was correct at the time of writing but changed in 2013 (https://github.com/git/git/commit/1190a1ac / https://github.com/git/git/commit/40a4f5a7). It is now the trailer checksum (equal to the hexadecimal of the last 20 bytes of the file).

Answer (score 6):

The answer is either "the SHA-1 hash of the entire pack file, minus the last 20 bytes", or "a hexadecimal digest of the last 20 bytes" (both are equivalent).

The [last 20 bytes of the file](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1190a1acf800acdcfd7569f87ac1560e2d077414) is the "trailer checksum" which itself is a [SHA-1 hash of the entirety of the file](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt) (minus the last 20 bytes).

This was [changed in 2013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1190a1acf800acdcfd7569f87ac1560e2d077414) (previously it was the SHA-1 sum of all the hashes in the file). Note that the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-objects.html) now simply reads " is a hash based on the pack content". The author explicitly does not guarantee how the SHA-1 is calculated (from the [commit log](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40a4f5a7bf0ffee4fa1fb954b1ebf5daba5bae75): "Hopefully this will discourage readers from depending on the old or the new calculation.").